# Nutch: Data read and adding metadata

Tags: solr, lucene, web-crawler, semantic-web, nutch

I recently started looking apache nutch. I could do setup and able to crawl web pages of my interest with nutch. I am not quite understanding on how to read this data. I basically want to associate data of each page with some metadata(some random data for now) and store them locally which will be later used for searching(semantic). Do I need to use solr or lucene for the same? I am new to all of these. As far I know Nutch is used to crawl web pages. Can it do some additional features like adding metadata to the crawled data?

Comment: Hi CRS, since you tagged your question with 'semantic-web' I assume you want to extract some structured data from the pages you want to crawl (either Microformats, RDFa and/or Microdata). If this is the case, it will save a lot of time looking at Any23 (http://incubator.apache.org/any23/) (which might be integrated with Nutch and probably someone is already trying to do that or done it already).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will take a look at Any23. I am actually crawling "normal" webpages. It is not associated with any metadata. We have some algorithm which computes metadata out of the text from these webpages. This metadata should be added to the local copy of the webpage. So I am looking for a crawler which crawls the webpages and extracts contents and then inserts metadata into the local copy of webpages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Useful commands.

Begin crawl

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

Get statistics of crawled URL's

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -stats
```

Read segment (gets all the data from web pages)

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* segmentAllContent
```

Read segment (gets only the text field)

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* segmentTextContent -nocontent -nofetch -nogenerate -     noparse -noparsedata
```

Get all list of known links to each URL, including both the source URL and anchor text of the link.

```
bin/nutch readlinkdb crawl/linkdb/ -dump linkContent
```

Get all URL's crawled. Also gives other information like whether it was fetched, fetched time, modified time etc.

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb/ -dump crawlContent
```

For the second part. i.e to add new field I am planning to use index-extra plugin or to write custom plugin.

Refer:

[this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-422) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample)